# Showing that the set of open disks $U:=\{B((0,r+1/r),r):r>1\}$ forms an open cover over the upper half-plane

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to demonstrate that the set of open disks
$$U:=\{B((0,r+1/r),r):r>1\}$$
forms an open cover over the upper half-plane. I have tried to show that for every $(x,y)$ in the upper half-plane, there exists an $r$ such that $d((x,y),(0,r+1/r))<r$, but it seems the harder I try, the more confused I get. I am not so good with formal proofs, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show $f(r)=r^2-\left( x_0^2+(y_0-r-\frac{1}{r})^2 \right)=2(r+\frac{1}{r})y_0-x_0^2-y_0^2-\frac{1}{r^2}-2>0$ for enough large $r$. This is almost obvious since this part $2(r+\frac{1}{r})y_0$ can be arbitrarily large, while the other part are bounded.